# How to make a program that will open a certain picture in the picturebox, depending on the text entered in the textbox. C# forms

Tags: c#, forms

I don't understand what to do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1 = "France")
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\user\proga ot alejandro\1.jpg");
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
           
        }


    }
}
```

I should make programm when i text a country name in textbox it will open a picture in picture box

I need help please. I would be kicked from the university if i wont make that programm.

Comment: The TextBox won't be equal to "France"...but the TEXT WITHIN it might. Change `textBox1` to `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: Why is button needed?

Comment: If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. If it provides some value give it an upvote. If it needs clarification add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your Text Changed event - then build on all your other countries that are needed.

```
if (textBox1.Text.ToLower() == "france")
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\path to picture");
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text.ToLower() == "us")
            {

                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\path to picture");

            }else if(continue on...){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions to put you on the right track (but please make sure that the final code you turn into "university" is something you can explain and justify ;).

First, put the images into a folder and set their properties to `Copy if Newer` so that they can be read from a known path at runtime.

[image: images folder]

This makes it easy to capture a list of the image file names when you start your program.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var folder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images");
        // Make an array of the image file names so you can search it.
        _images = 
            Directory
            .GetFiles(folder)
            .ToArray();
        textBoxSearch.TextChanged += ontextBoxSearchChanged;
    }
}
private string[] _images;
```

Then, when the text changes, you can use a `System.Linq` expression or some other method to search this list for matches (making sure *not* to consider the extension or the folder path). Just make certain that this search functionality "knows what to do" if it finds multiple matches.

```
private void ontextBoxSearchChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do not block on this event.
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
    {
        string[] matches;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxSearch.Text))
        {
            matches = new string[0];
        }
        else
        {
            // Use Linq to detect matches
            matches = 
                _images
                .Where(_ => 
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_)
                    .Contains(textBoxSearch.Text)
                ).ToArray();
        }
        labelMatchCount.Text = $"{matches.Length} matches";
        if(matches.Length.Equals(1))
        {
            // Found a single match
            labelMatchCount.Visible = false;
            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(matches.First());
        }
        else
        {
            // Found multiple matches
            pictureBox.Image = null;
            labelMatchCount.Visible = true;
        }
    });
}
```

[image: runtime]